# Docker app not available with host IP when using automatic port mapping

Tags: docker

I am deploying a eureka server on a VM(say host external IP is a.b.c.d) as a docker image. Trying this in 2 ways.

1.I am running the docker image without explicit port mapping : **docker run -p 8671 test/eureka-server**
   Then running docker ps command shows the port mapping as : **0.0.0.0:32769->8761/tcp**
   Try accessing the eureka server from outside of the VM with **http://a.b.c.d:32769 , its not available.**

2.I am running the docker image with explicit port mapping : **docker run -p 8761:8761 test/eureka-server**
   Then running docker ps command shows the port mapping as : **0.0.0.0:8761->8761/tcp**
   Try accessing the eureka server from outside of the VM with **http://a.b.c.d:8761 , its available.**

Why in the first case the eureka server is not available from out side the host machine even if there is a random port(32769) assigned by docker. 
Is it necessary to have explicit port mapping to have docker app available from external network ?

Comment: My first question would be, are you sure that `tcp/32769` is open to the outside world on any firewalls you may have. Could you try explicitly mapping that port `docker run -p 32769:8761 test/eureka-server` and trying to access it?

Comment: Thanks. ..Looks like that can be the issue. Its not available even when explicitly mapping the port 32769:8671.  In that case dynamic port mapping by docker can be used only with a range of ports which we know that is exposed to outside world ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're looking for access from the outside world to the host via the mapped port you'll need to ensure that the source traffic is allowed to reach that port on the host and given protocol. I'm not a network security specialist, but I'd suggest that opening up an entire range of ports simply because you don't know which port docker will pick would be a bad idea. If you can, I'd say pick a port and explicitly map it and ensure the firewall allows access to that port from the appropriate source address(es) e.g. `ALLOW TCP/8671` in from `10.0.1.2/32` as an example - obviously your specific address range will vary on your network configuration. Docker compose may help you keep this consistent (as will other orchestration technologies like Kubernetes). In addition if you use cloud hosting services like AWS you may be able to leverage VPC security groups to help you whitelist source traffic to the port without knowing all possible source IP addresses ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

You either have the firewall blocking this port, or from wherever you are making the requests, for certain ports your outgoing traffic is disabled, so your requests never leave your machine.

Some companies do this. They leave port 80, 443, and couple of more for their intranet, and disable all other destination ports.